# Appstore iOS 8 requirements

Tags: ios, xcode

I just like to have second thoughts to confirm my doubts about the new app store requirements [here](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=10202014a)

Questions:

1. If I build my app using the latest version (iOS 8 SDK), can we install it on lower ios version such as 7.x.x? No?
2. If I want backward compatibility of my apps, where in the user can install in iOS 8 and older version, is it possible?
3. With the latest requirement, must I set the deployment target to 8.0 and later to get approved in appstore?

Answer (score 0):

Questions 1 and 2 sound very similar.

The decisive factor is the minimum deployment target you choose. It will determine the minimum iOS version your app will run on.

However, there are things that work differently in different versions of iOS. So you might need to add a check for the iOS version your app currently runs on in your code.

Answer (score 0):

It means you have to **build** with iOS 8 SDK. If you need to support 7.0 and higher, you can set your *deployment target* to lower version. Just watch your code, as the APIs differ.